# Java ServerSocket sometimes randomly doesn't receive client data

Tags: java, sockets, server, java.util.scanner, inputstream

I was writing a basic HTTP server to host some files. Along the way I wanted to test that the server was receiving client data. Using the below code, a `NoSuchElementException` exception is thrown. The Scanner isn't receiving the line from the client, even though it does for the most part. Here's the code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Simple {


    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(80);
            while(true){
                try{
                    Socket sock = ss.accept();
                    InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
                    out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-type:text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
                    out.write(sc.nextLine().getBytes());
                    sock.close();
                } catch(Exception ex){
                    System.err.println(ex);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When this happens, the client connection waits for a very long time before the connection drops or the server finally receives client data. Any help is appreciated.

No, this isn't a duplicate of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273794/scanner-nextline-nosuchelementexception). (These are two separate questions).

Comment: To stop the client hanging you need to close the socket in the catch block or better still use `try (Socket sock = ss.accept()) { ... } catch ...`

Comment: Kudos on the [mcve] for the server.  To actually troubleshoot this we need to know what's at the client end of the connection.  Is it code you wrote or a browser or something else.

Comment: I wonder if you are confusing the client by sending a response before the client has sent the request. This might explain the intermittant behaviour.

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior you are seeing by running your code then using `telnet localhost 80`, entering some data (without a newline) and then closing the connection.  Everything hinges on knowing what the client is and how it might react to getting the `200 OK` response before actually submitting a request, as @PhilipCouling suggests.

Comment: Side comment: I hope you're writing an HTTP server as a self-education exercise because, given the availability of lightweight servers (Nginx, etc) your time is much better spent configuring one of those.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Okay, I'll try that. JimGarrison It's a browser, I didn't write it myself. I'm using Opera 49.0.2725.47, which is the latest version at the moment. This is purely just for the learning experience, as I know that there are other HTTP servers out there better than mine could ever be. It seems that sending data after receiving it from the browser has fixed the issue. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate: the behaviour you observe is entirely explained by the reason for the `NoSuchElementException`. Or else you're asking two questions at once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Scanner.hasNextLine()` before `Scanner.nextLine()`, otherwise it will certainly trhrow this exception. It has nothing to do with the socket: it is the defined behaviour of `Scanner. NB Java`ServerSocket`*never* receives data. An accepted`Socket` does that at the server side.