# NoSuchElementException error occured in java (Scanner error)

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

I just tried to get an integer value from the user for a variable in another a method that created differently from main but it gives an error message like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:941)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1598)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2263)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2217)
    at StoreUsingArrays_20210808043.menu(StoreUsingArrays_20210808043.java:14)
    at StoreUsingArrays_20210808043.storeRun(StoreUsingArrays_20210808043.java:57)
    at StoreUsingArrays_20210808043.main(StoreUsingArrays_20210808043.java:90)
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class StoreUsingArrays_20210808043 {
    
    public static int menu(String[] items,double[] prices,int answer) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 1;i <= items.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(i+" - for "+items[i-1]+" ("+prices[i-1]+")");
        }
        System.out.println("0 - to checkout");
        System.out.print("Please enter what would you like : ");
        answer = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your choice was : "+answer);
        input.close();
        return answer;
    }
    
    public static void returnedAmounts(double amount) {
        double bill200,bill100,bill50,bill20,bill10,bill5,bill1,coin50,coin25,coin10,coin1;
        bill200 = (amount - (amount%200)) / 200;
        amount = amount%200;
        bill100 = (amount - (amount%100)) / 100;
        amount = amount%100;
        bill50 = (amount - (amount%50)) / 50;
        amount = amount%50;
        bill20 = (amount - (amount%20)) / 20;
        amount = amount%20;
        bill10 = (amount - (amount%10)) / 10;
        amount = amount%10;
        bill5 = (amount -(amount%5)) / 5;
        amount = amount%5;
        bill1 = (amount - (amount%1)) / 1;
        amount = amount%1;
        coin50 = (amount - (amount%0.50)) / 0.50;
        amount = amount%0.50;
        coin25 = (amount - (amount%0.25)) / 0.25;
        amount = amount%0.25;
        coin10 = (amount - (amount%0.10)) / 0.10;
        amount = amount%0.10;
        coin1 = (amount - (amount%0.01)) / 0.01;
        double[] returnedNumbers = {bill200,bill100,bill50,bill20,bill10,bill5,bill1,coin50,coin25,coin10,coin1};
        double[] returnedValues = {200,100,50,20,10,5,1,0.50,0.25,0.10,0.01};
        for (int i = 0;i < returnedNumbers.length;i++) {
            if ((returnedNumbers[i] > 0) && (returnedValues[i] > 0)) {
                System.out.println((int)returnedNumbers[i]+" - "+returnedValues[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void storeRun(String[] item,int[] quantity,double[] price) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        capitalizeArray(item);
        int choice,req = 0;
        while (true) {
            choice = menu(item, price, 0);
            if (choice == 0) break;
            else if (choice > item.length && choice < 0) {
                System.out.println("ERROR:Invalid choice");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("How many "+item[choice-1]+" would you like? ");
                if (input.hasNextInt()) req = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println(req);
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
    
    public static String capitalizeString(String text) {
        return text.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + text.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    
    public static String[] capitalizeArray(String[] name) {
        for (int i = 0;i < name.length;i++) {
            name[i] = capitalizeString(name[i]);
        }
        return name;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] item = {"bRead","cOLA","ROLL","BaKe"};
        double[] price = {4,2,6,5};
        int[] quantity = {10,25,17,22};
        //capitalizeArray(item);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(item));
        //menu(item, price, 0);
        storeRun(item, quantity, price);
        //returnedAmounts(167.5);
    }

}
```

I expected to get a value for the req variable from user and use it for another purposes but I tried a lot of things like that:

- Initializing the variable at the begin.
- Removing the input.close() line.
  (etc.)
  But all of them didn't work.

Comment: It's not recommended to close `System.in`, see [here](https://coderanch.com/wiki/678613/Don-close-Scanner-tied-System)

Comment: Don't keep creating and closing the `Scanner`. In fact don't close it at all on stdin. One `Scanner` only, as a `static` class variable though see [this](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/108-static-is-a-swear-word)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner nextLine() NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273794/scanner-nextline-nosuchelementexception)

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace all `input.close()` by `input.reset()`
2. In method `menu`, replace `answer = input.nextInt();` by `if (input.hasNextInt()) answer = input.nextInt();`

and it should work

Comment: It worked I did everything like that you said thank you. But I didn't understand why it didn't work at the first time.

Comment: Have a look à look at the doc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt